# How I Loop/Repeat the program base on the value of user input?

Tags: java, eclipse

Example i have the simple program as below:

```
 Scanner guess = new Scanner(System.in);
 Scanner play = new Scanner(System.in);

 int count =0;
 int sum=0;
 int num, N;
 int ply, T;

 System.out.println("How many times will you play?");
 T = play.nextInt();



System.out.println("How many numbers will you enter?");
 N = guess.nextInt();



 for(count =0; count < N; count++)
 {
     System.out.println("Enter a number");
     num = guess.nextInt();
     sum +=num;
 }

     System.out.println("The sum of the numbers entered is:"+sum);
```

how do i repeat/loop the program start from "enter a number", base on the "how many times will you play?"

that means the program will repeat base on the value user input before.

example,
user input want play 5 times
then the program will repeat/loop 5 times start from enter a number.

pls... help me... thanks guy.. u guy are genius.!

Answer (score 2):

You basically already answered yourself:

Just do another for loop on the T variable (which should have a lowercase name btw):

```
System.out.println("How many times will you play?"); T = play.nextInt();

for (int playNum = 0; playNum < T; playNum++)
{
    sum = 0; // Don't forget to reset sum on each iteration
    System.out.println("How many numbers will you enter?"); N = guess.nextInt();

    for(count =0; count < N; count++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        num = guess.nextInt();
        sum +=num;
    }
    System.out.println("The sum of the numbers entered is:"+sum);
}
```

Comment: thanks! finally figure it out.... i missed the int for play count. You guy are awesome ! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You only need one `Scanner`. Your variable names are a little confusing (and I would prefer more limited lexical scope). Finally, you could use a loop. Like,

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("How many times will you play?");
int plays = scan.nextInt();
for (int playCount = 0; playCount < plays; playCount++) {
    System.out.println("How many numbers will you enter?");
    int numbers = scan.nextInt();
    int sum = 0;
    for (int count = 0; count < numbers; count++) {
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        int num = scan.nextInt();
        sum += num;
    }
    System.out.println("The sum of the numbers entered is:" + sum);
}
```

Comment: thanks! finally figure it out.... i missed the int for play count. You guy are awesome ! Thanks!